# How to overcome jest "Cannot access before initialization" problem?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

**settings.js**

```
export default {
  web: {
    a: 1
  },
  mobile: {
    b: 2
  }
};
```

**getSetting.js**

```
import settings from "./settings";

export const getSetting = platform => {
  return settings[platform];
};
```

**getSettings.test.js**

```
import { getSetting } from "./getSetting";

const TEST_SETTINGS = { c: 3 };

jest.mock("./settings", () => {
  return {
    test: TEST_SETTINGS
  };
});

test("getSetting", () => {
  expect(getSetting("test")).toEqual(TEST_SETTINGS);
});
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'TEST_SETTINGS' before initialization
```

I believe this has something to do with hoisting. Is there a way to overcome this issue? Does jest provide any other means to achieve this?

I don't want to do this. This is not good when the mock data is large and used in multiple tests.

```
jest.mock("./settings", () => {
  return {
    test: { c: 3 }
  };
});

expect(getSetting("test")).toEqual({ c: 3 });
```

Answer (score 7):

`jest.mock` is [automatically hoisted](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports), this results in evaluating mocked module before `TEST_SETTINGS` is declared.

Also, this results in `./settings` being mocked with `test` named export, while it's expected to have default export.

It shouldn't use temporary variable, the value is available when it's being imported:

```
import settings from "./settings";

jest.mock("./settings", () => {
  return { default: {
    test: { c: 3 }
  } };
});

...

expect(getSetting("test")).toBe(settings.test);
```

Answer (score 4):

Or, use [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) `import()`.

E.g.

```js
const TEST_SETTINGS = { c: 3 };

jest.mock('./settings', () => {
  return {
    test: TEST_SETTINGS,
  };
});

test('getSetting', async () => {
  const { getSetting } = await import('./getSetting');
  expect(getSetting('test')).toEqual(TEST_SETTINGS);
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/61843762/getSettings.test.js
  ✓ getSetting (4 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.25 s, estimated 4 s
```

jestjs version: `"jest": "^26.6.3"`