# How to force a return value of a function in jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am trying  to test some code that relies on an api returning some data. Currently, I  am able to  mock the call of listNamespacedIngress in this function:

```
async function getIngress(namespace) {
  try {
    const result = await k8sIngressApi.listNamespacedIngress(namespace, true);
    const resultSpec = result.body.items.filter(e => e.metadata.name === deploymentPrefix)[0];
    if (!resultSpec) {
      throw new TypeError('Ingress spec is undefined');
    }
    return resultSpec;
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}
```

using a jest.mock and mocking the return value of that function in this library, as seen here:

```
jest.mock('@kubernetes/client-node', () => ({
  KubeConfig: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    loadFromCluster: jest.fn(),
    loadFromDefault: jest.fn(),
    makeApiClient: () => ({
      listNamespacedIngress: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
          body: {
            items: [
              {
                metadata: {
                  name: 'a',
                  namespace: 'b',
                },
                spec: {
                  rules: [
                    {
                      host: 'url.com',
                      http: {
                        paths: [
                          {
                            backend: {
                              serviceName: 'a',
                              servicePort: 80,
                            },
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
```

This way, I am able to test the initial return value if resultSpec doesnt end up being  undefined, as seen here (this test passes):

```
  it('Should return storybook-staging ingress details', async () => {
    // When
    const result = await getIngress();

    // Then
    expect(result.metadata.name).toEqual('a');
  });
```

However, I am unsure how I can force listNamespacedIngress to come back as undefined?

EDIT: Added full use of module

```
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();
const k8sDeploymentApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.AppsV1Api);
const k8sServiceApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);
const k8sIngressApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.NetworkingV1beta1Api);

const BRANCH_NAME = process.argv.slice(2)[0].toLowerCase();
const NAMESPACE = 'dev';
const deploymentPrefix = 'storybook-staging';

const DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG = getDeploymentConfig(deploymentPrefix, BRANCH_NAME);
const SERVICE_CONFIG = getServiceConfig(deploymentPrefix, BRANCH_NAME);
const INGRESS_CONFIG = getIngressConfig(deploymentPrefix);

const HTTP_CONFLICT = 409;

process.on('exit', code => {
  console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`);
});

async function getIngress(namespace) {
  try {
    const result = await k8sIngressApi.listNamespacedIngress(namespace, true);
    console.log(result);
    const resultSpec = result.body.items.filter(e => e.metadata.name === deploymentPrefix)[0];
    if (!resultSpec) {
      throw new TypeError('Ingress spec is undefined');
    }
    return resultSpec;
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way for `listNamespacedIngress` to change return values is to make it Jest spy. Since it's nested and cannot be easily referred in tests, it should be defined outside module mock:

```
// should be var because jest.mock is hoisted
var mockListNamespacedIngress;

jest.mock('@kubernetes/client-node', () => {
  mockListNamespacedIngress = jest.fn();

  return {
  KubeConfig: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    loadFromCluster: jest.fn(),
    loadFromDefault: jest.fn(),
    makeApiClient: () => ({
      listNamespacedIngress: mockListNamespacedIngress
      ...
```

This also allows to assert that the function was called:

```
mockListNamespacedIngress.mockResolvedValue({ body: { items: [...] } });
await expect(getIngress()).resolves.toEqual('a');
expect(mockListNamespacedIngress).toBeCalledWith(...);

...

mockListNamespacedIngress.mockResolvedValue({ body: { items: [] } });
await expect(getIngress()).rejects.toThrow(TypeError);
expect(mockListNamespacedIngress).toBeCalledWith(...);
```

Comment: Actually if I could just ask one more question! When I run this, Im getting undefined when trying to read body.items etc. When I console log the value of result, I get this
{ [Function: mockConstructor]
      _isMockFunction: true,
...
...
      }

So it seems it's returning the values of the mock object itself as opposed to the values I gave it?

Edit: I also seem to be getting that mockListNamespacedIngress is not defined, though it is at the top of the file and is referenced in my implementation mock

Comment: There may be a problem if KubeConfig is called instantly on import. Please, update the question with a module where KubeConfig is used. It's unclear what's the relationship between a module where getIngress is defined and `@kubernetes/client-node`. The way the latter is mocked may depend on that.

Comment: I see. `kc` could be mocked instead of entire `KubeConfig` if it were instantiated in separate module. But since it's declared and used in the same module, it's still easier to expose a spy as mockListNamespacedIngress variable to access it. Updated the post.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using var? I currently have quite stringent eslint rules, however when I use let (presumably because it isn't hoisted), mockListNamespacedIngress becomes undefined

Comment: Not in any meaningful way I'm aware of. You can expose a spy on mocked module with ` () => { let mockListNamespacedIngress = jest.fn(); return { mockListNamespacedIngress, KubeConfig: ...`  and import it like `import { mockListNamespacedIngress } from  '@kubernetes/client-node'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843762/how-to-overcome-jest-cannot-access-before-initialization-problem but using dummy export doesn't seem justified for one-time use, this would make sense if a mock were stored in `__mocks__`.

Comment: Btw `let` instead of `var` with `jest.mock` should have cause this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843762  instead of making mockListNamespacedIngress silently undefined. The only reason for this I can think of is that tests are transpiled to ES5. Since Jest runs in Node, this may be unnecessary and harmful. Check Jest config if ES5 is not desirable.

Comment: Cool. I'll stop bugging you now, thank you so much for all your help, really helped me along the way here :D